# How to make appbar with some button and handle up button with navigation

Tags: android, toolbar, android-architecture-navigation, appbar

I want to make a custom toolbar that I can add two or more buttons to navigating some other section (like profile and the notification area) and current fragment name. and if I user change fragment and go to another place up button disappear for back to the last place. right now I try to handle like this:

`appbar.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:appNs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:theme="@style/toolbarTheme">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="my app name"
        android:layout_gravity = "center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/main_bold"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgProfile"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgNotification"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_notification"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"/>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

`activity_main.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/appbar" />

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/myNavHostFragment"
                    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:defaultNavHost="true"
                    app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />
            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

`MainActivity.kt:`

```
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
        toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

how I can set onClickListener for ImageView that defined into appbar.xml? 
and how I can make label fragment text customizable? for example change font text size and text color and ...
(right now when I go into one fragment and user up button to back label fragment will go to edge or disappear and go out from toolbar section)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use databinding, you can access child views of your included view easily. You need to provide `id` to your included layout. Simply add databinding to your included layout, and then access its views using it.
In your case in your main activity it would be something like:

```
binding.toolbar.imgProfile.setOnClickListener{}
```

Comment: thank you, it's work. can you help me with the text for navigation? I use the Persian language for label fragment in the home page before the up button disappears and this text will go out screen. how I can fix it?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand your question. Maybe resolve this question, and post a new one with code snippets and data flow.